# What are the box characters often used in terminal prompts?

Tags: unicode, terminal

I have seen this image on the catpuccin windows terminal port:
[image: catpuccin windows terminal port example]
I believe the box around the prompt is achieved by setting the background colour, but what are the symbols on the left and right of the prompt?

I have looked in unicode box drawing as well as block elements, but with no luck. A google search yields no useful results other than libraries that create the prompts for you (like ohmyposh).

Comment: When you say ‘symbols’ do you mean shapes? Or are you referring to the tilde?

Comment: Yes, the semicircle and right arrow characters

Comment: I have found these characters:  (use a nerd font to view) but i am still missing the character before the tilde

Comment: U+25D6 is potentially the semi circle Unicode

Comment: It is not flush with the other characters. I have found a character for the semicircle () that works with nerd fonts. As well as the right arrow (). However the shape before the `~` is still a mystery to me.

Comment: I have looked through every nerd font character and that shape is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the characters can be found by looking through nerd fonts.
This code will display all nerd fonts characters (make sure to use a nerd font to view):

```js
(async function() {
  const res = await fetch("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/h5vx/e860699d12646dd436e6ab858809b7 
  const json = JSON.parse(await res.text());
  json.forEach(c => { document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>" + Object.values(c)) + "</p>" });
})();
```

Near the end of this list, the following characters can be found:

- : >
- : (]

However one of the characters does not exist in nerd fonts. Here is the closest I have gotten to the original image:

[image: an image of the prompt in a nice terminal window]

EDIT: the final character is simply the character at the end of the prompt with the bg & fg flipped.